# Can we use the different version of same package in a single Flutter project?

Tags: flutter

I'm working on an app that was developed by some other developer who used the older version of the google_mobile_ads package (To be specific, it was google_mobile_ads: ^0.12.2+1).

Now I'm trying to implement a new feature of that package that is only available in the newer version of that same package. (To be specific, it is google_mobile_ads: ^0.13.6).

I don't want to update the old codes using that package, because there of thousands of lines which will consume a lot of time.

So is there any way I can use the same package twice with different versions in the same app?

Comment: No! If you try to add the same package twice, it will give an error just after reading the name of the package.

Answer (score 2):

No , you can't use same package twice with different version , Because if you define it in your `pubspec.yaml` file , then it throws an error for declaring same package with different versions and you can't move further in your code.

Comment: Then how can I solve the problem mentioned in the Question?

Comment: You just update new version of that package and then solve an error in your code if any to because of that new package , Simple :)